# Veins LTE Omnet++ Error

Tags: omnet++, lte, veins

I have successfully run the example veins LTE sceranio on Ubuntu 14.04, Sumo-0.22, Omnet++-4.6 using the command ./run (no debug)

The heterogeneous.rou.xml file has more nodes marked as comments. When I add some new nodes from this file I get an error

```
<!> Error in module (HeterogeneousToLTE) scenario.node[0].heterogeneousToLTE (id=58) at event #21075, t=5.6: IPvXAddressResolver: module `node[3]' not found.
```

Is it possible to run the scenario with a command or a change to ingore the nodes that will be not found? before I continue with my own scenario map and route files.

Do you know how to sovle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that no node[3] exists. Make sure that this node is already in the simulation.
Please note that the `SimpleApp` is a very basic application, you might have to extend your application so that it sends the messages to the correct car.